# How to display Java Multi threading output in jsp file

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp

I have a Java Program which contains my own thread (start() and run() methods). Code is shown below :

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void threadStart()
    {
        Threadone t1 = new Threadone();
        t1.start();
    }

}
class Threadone extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306";
        String user= "root";
        String pwd = "root@123";
        String qry = "SELECT Country FROM test.abuse WHERE Priority='High'";
        Connection conn = null;
        try 
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);

            ResultSet rs = conn.prepareStatement(qry).executeQuery();

            while(rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("Country"));
            }
        } 
        catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**JSP File:**

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%
        MyClass my = new MyClass();
        my.threadStart();
    %>
    </body>
    </html>
```

As of now I am displaying the result in java console. But my task is to display the result in jsp file, Is it possible? If possible how to print the data in webpage using jsp file?

Comment: using ajax maybe?

Comment: Are you fine to get all your console output in one jsp page load, or you need to see thread work interactively - like update jsp once thread did every portion of work?

Comment: Yup, I need to update jsp once thread did every portion of work

Comment: Then AJAX or Websocket would be the way to go. You will need to create some javaScript on client side (in your jsp as option) and call your server to dynamically update your front end. The server side should contain some service servlet to report thread progress. Also it could be nice to do it in reactive way. Seems like few questions actually here.

Comment: But I don't know how to use Javascript. please provide any solution

Answer (score 2):

Create a shared collection like map or list .The background thread will populate into the shared collection.And through AJAX or other mechanism fetch from the shared collection.Consider thread safety as it required multiple thread will access the collection while background thread is processing.

Comment: Can u explain more briefly please

Comment: Create a singleton store which will contain your data.store method will store the data and fetch method use by jsp.make all method thread safe